# Difference between cross_val_score and estimator score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using Scikit-learn. I tried using cross validation using plain cross validation procedure and the quick `cross_validation.cross_val_score`. But I found that I'm getting different numbers. Why?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation, datasets

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

kfold = cross_validation.KFold(len(X))
scores = [svc.fit(X[train], y[train]).score(X[test], y[test]) for train, test in kfold]

#scores output: [0.93489148580968284, 0.95659432387312182, 0.93989983305509184]

cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc, X, y)
#output: array([ 0.98 ,  0.982,  0.983])
```

Comment: Is it possible it's computing different kinds of cross-val scores (e.g., mean squared error vs. mean absolute error)?

Comment: @BrenBarn: no, it uses `svc.score` in both cases. Since `SVC` is a classifier, it will compute mean accuracy. The difference is in the cross-validation itself, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docstring for `cross_val_score` will tell you, it does *stratified* cross validation when giving a target vector of class labels (integers).

```
>>> kfold = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y)
>>> [svc.fit(X[train], y[train]).score(X[test], y[test])
...  for train, test in kfold]
[0.93521594684385378, 0.95826377295492482, 0.93791946308724827]
>>> cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc, X, y)
array([ 0.93521595,  0.95826377,  0.93791946])
```